# java.lang.NullPointerException in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, fragment

currently I'm developing an application of android. but I have a problem it.

a scenario is it as follows :

1) start a application

2) select a tab about google map v2

3) click Keycode_back to finish the application.

4) then I can see error message about java.lang.NullPointerException from LogCat of ADT.

```
public class Fragment_Section1 extends Fragment {

public Fragment_Section1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

GoogleMap gMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflat and return the layout
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_section1,
            container, false);

    GoogleMap gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();

    // To configure any camera updates here

    LatLng ku = new LatLng(37.545833, 127.082778);

    // gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ku, 15));

    // gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("KU")
    // .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.").position(ku));

    return rootView;
}

public void onDestroyView() {
    SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
    if (smf != null)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(smf)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
}
```

layout : layout_fragment_section1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat :

```
12-18 14:39:03.034: D/AndroidRuntime(24730): Shutting down VM
12-18 14:39:03.034: W/dalvikvm(24730): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x424f9700)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
12-18 14:39:03.034: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can you give me an advice ?

Let me know if yo need any information.

Best Regards,

Comment: add this line `super.onDestroyView();` at the end of onDestroyView(); method.

Comment: use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager();

Comment: is `mapView` is in `layout_fragment_section1` layout?

Comment: HI @Ketan Thank for adding comment. a minute ago it was add at the end of onDestroyView().

Comment: hi @RBM Thanks for adding comment. I used getSupportFragmentManger instead of getFragmentManager. but It was same status.

Comment: hi @AbhishekV Thnks for addming comment. yes the mapView is in layout_fragment_section1 layout.